# Android: package android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

So im trying to implement a barcode scanner functionallity
And i have this piece of code

```
 private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(addquantityactivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

and i get this error `error: package android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog does not exist new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(addquantityactivity.this)`

To mention, i use androidx and i have tried the following imports..Also other solutions on stackoverflow didnt helped me.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: Remove android.support.v7.app from android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder()

Comment: If you are using AndroidX (and, since it is 2020, you should be), simply get rid of the `android.support.v7.app` portion of your code snippet, leaving you with `new AlertDialog.Builder`. Then your `import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` will supply the appropriate `AlertDialog` and `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Comment: it was so simple,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I hope this will work. If AlertDialog not imported then re-import the **androidx** version.

```
private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(addquantityactivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```